# How to Download source code of existing smart contracts on ethereum block chain

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan

We are working on a project which requires smart contract source codes for analysis in ethereum blockchain.

Can anyone suggest us how to download the source codes of various smart contracts already existing on the blockchain?
Thanks.

Comment: You obviously cannot download source code directly from the blockchain because the blockchain consists of states, not source code. You can download the source code of a given contract address from services like etherscan.io, but only if the contract's deployer has bothered to complete the process of contract-verification on that service.

Comment: Thanks for the information. We tried getting the source code of smart contracts from etherscan.io. But we were able to get only about ~5000 smart contracts using an api key ( which are available under 'verified contracts' category). 

Also, we were able to find out that some people were able to get ~20000 contracts way back in 2016. We need much more than 5000 contracts. Are we missing some obvious solutions? Can you suggest any other solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can download the bytecode itself and then reverse engineer it. There are probably designated tools for that. The only undecipherable part in the bytecode which I can thing of is names of functions and variables, but those are just code symbols, right? So you shouldn't care too much about not being able to reproduce them... Oh, it also apply for comments in the code, but you probably care about those even less...