# How to download source code ( In solidity ) of already existing smart contracts on ethereum blockchain?

Tags: solidity, etherscan

We are working on a project which requires smart contract source codes for analysis in ethereum blockchain.

Can anyone suggest us how to download the source codes( In solidity) of various smart contracts already existing on the blockchain?

We tried getting the source code of smart contracts from etherscan.io. But we were able to get only about ~5000 smart contracts using an api key ( which are available under 'verified contracts' category).

Also, we were able to find out that some people were able to get ~20000 contracts way back in 2016. We need much more than 5000 contracts. Are we missing some obvious solutions? Can you suggest any other solutions. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of [your previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/80519/16043).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Download source code of existing smart contracts on ethereum block chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80519/how-to-download-source-code-of-existing-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-block-chain)

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan has a [bytecode decompiler](https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler) to turn bytecode into more human readable code. While it is still experimental, depending on the analysis you are doing this might give you some more data.

Edit: Scanning github repos is a good way too. Check out this report by Electric Capital: https://www.electriccapital.com/electric-research

> We fingerprinted 27,000+ code repositories and 22 million code commits to create this H1 2019 Developer Report.

This includes more than just Ethereum, but all their methods are open source on their github, so you can take a look there.